# node-red: multi users dashboard + node-red-contrib-users

Tags: authentication, dashboard, node-red, multi-user

I'm trying to use node-red to create a multi-user dashboard,
the idea is that the dashboard has different session, each for a different user. A user must be identificated by the system and can't reach the dashboard resources of another user.

I find the [multiuser dashboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-mdashboard) very useful to this scope, and I try to use it with [node-red-contrib-user](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-users) to obtain a login system that manages different types of account.
I make this flow:

[image: flow to redirect in different user dashboard]

but when I try to open the node-red-url/mui it redirect me directly to default user, without let me check the login.

The contrib-user works properly on sections that are different from dashboard (/mui or /ui)
It is possible to use the contrib on dashboard or it's better to think to another strategy?

Kind Regards,
Gianluca